# Minix 3 stdio.h doesn't recognize FILE *f

Tags: c, stdio, minix

I'm developing something on `Minix 3` and, when it comes to deal with io files, I got a problem.
In the code:

```
#include <stdio.h> /* If I don't call any stdio funcs compiler doesnt's complain*/
int main() {
  FILE * fp; /* I get the following: " * not expected " */
  return 0;
}
```

Already tried everything that comes to my mind, can't figure it out..

/*EDIT*/
From what I can tell, when I include something, if I call functions not related to structs, it's OK. Is it the structs ?

Comment: Is this the whole code, you got? Or there's something more?

Comment: If you add `int main() { return 0; }` after these lines and try to compile only this, do you still get the error?

Comment: Yes, this code is in the main..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you have checked whether the Minix file is present, that it really defines the type `FILE` and that your include path provides the correct `-I`option to the compiler to find that file.

Depending on your environment it could happen that an environment variable `INCLUDE` exists and is recognized by your compiler to provide additional include paths, recognized even before the include options from the command line. In such a case it might happen to include a `stdio.h`from a different compiler. Visual Studio is known to provide such an environment variable by default, and that has bitten me once before.

EDIT: Running the preprocessor in isolation may help to find out what is really happening in any case. Verify that `FILE`is defined in the preprocessed version of your file.